# What is wrong with this Cypher query?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to send the following to Neo4j using the REST interface, specifically the method given in the 2.2.9 manual tutorial on using REST from Java, sendTransactional Cypher query. However, as you can see below, I keep on getting an error that doesn't seem to have much to do with the query itself.

Any tips on how I can debug this?

```
CREATE (p:player { props }), "parameters" { 
     "props" : { 
          "screen_name" : "testone", 
          "email" : "test.one@gmail.com", 
          "rank" : "-12", 
          "password" : "testonepass", 
          "details" : "test one details", 
          "latitude" : "0.0", 
          "longitude" : "0.0", 
          "available" : "true", 
          "publish" : "true" }}
```

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@10401de; line: 1, column: 66]"}]}
```

Comment: The error says the thing is shocking on "p:", so I don't see how "I keep on getting an error that doesn't seem to have much to do with the query itself." apply

Comment: You might be constructing wrong the request. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989613/create-a-node-in-neo4j-graph-db-with-transaction-endpoint

Comment: Yeah, but it also objects to column 66, which does not have a 'p' character.

Comment: missing colon after "parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

Form the snippet you posted, it looks like the payload to the transactional endpoint is incomplete. You could try this statement in the browser.  I just copied your statement and formatted it so it could be posted to the browser. Then you can at least see it work. Clearly the data is being posted and it seems it is just comes down to formatting.

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {
"statements": [
    {
        "statement": "CREATE (p:player { props })",
        "parameters": 
            {
                "props" : { 
                    "screen_name" : "testone", 
                    "email" : "test.one@gmail.com", 
                    "rank" : "-12", 
                    "password" : "testonepass", 
                    "details" : "test one details", 
                    "latitude" : "0.0", 
                    "longitude" : "0.0", 
                    "available" : "true", 
                    "publish" : "true" }  
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Following the code in the manual's tutorial, 'statements' and 'statement' are being added later. Sorry for forgetting that. Here is the complete query and reply: